# How to set variable inside a xib / NIB in swift

Tags: swift, xib, getter-setter

cannot modify value for a variable in my XIB class. How can I set variable from the didLoad of ViewController the value of `var orientation` ? I only get printed always the initial default value I set in the class .none

in my VC

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                    
        self.myTestCustomView.orientation = .square
       
    }
```

my class

```
enum Orientation: String, CaseIterable {
    case none
    case horizontalRectangle, verticalRectangle, square
}

class CustomView : UIView {
    @IBOutlet private var contentView:UIView?
    // other outlets
    
    private var _orientation: Orientation = .none
    var orientation: Orientation {
        set { _orientation = newValue }
        get {return _orientation}
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
        guard let content = contentView else { return }
        content.frame = self.bounds
        content.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.addSubview(content)
        
        print("checkValue\(_orientation.rawValue)")
        
        self.setNeedsLayout()

    }
}
```

EDIT:

my solution, removed `_orientation`, accessing from VC directly to `orientation`. any advice or comment welcomed.

```
var orientation: Orientation {

  set {
        switch newValue {
        case .horizontalRectangle:
            self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 5.0 //height since is orizzontal rectangle
        case .verticalRectangle:
            self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 5.0
        case.square:
            self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 5.0
        case .none:
            self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius =  0.0
        }
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }
    
    get {return self.orientation}

}
```

Comment: You can modify it, no? It's just that `commonInit()` will be called before you do `self.myTestCustomView.orientation = .square`. You can add a "reload" when that variable change, or maybe use IBDesignable to be able to set it in your xib.

Comment: I'm not able to modify it, the value remain ".none" when in VC I set different value. Please, could you show me what you mean with "reload" ?

Comment: updated a solution, what do you think about?